# Random arrangement of pixel in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to random rearrangement position of pixels in one image but the value of the pixel does not change. Can give me some ideas how I'm going to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it random within the rows or columns or entire image? Also, is it a grayscale image?

Comment: i want random for entire image. image using is grayscale @Divakar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html)

```
img = imread( ... ); % read image
rimg = reshape( img, [], size(img,3) ); % arrange as 1D image with x-channels
n = size(rimg,1); % how many pixels you have
simg = rimg( randperm(n), : ); % shuffle pixels
simg = reshape( simg, size(img) ); % reshape back
```